# Visual Studio 2010: Build DLL project before 'Active' project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a solution consisting of 2 projects. One is a DLL, and the other is a console app making use of this DLL (runtime). The console app is set as my active project and when I run (F5), it is started (optionally rebuilt first).

I want to make Visual Studio 2010 rebuild the DLL project everytime I run my console app. How can I do this?

Comment: Mmm, the console app project doesn't depend on any artifact defined in the project that generates the .DLL assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right click on the solution and select "Project Dependencies" you can tell it that your exe depends on the DLL and it should rebuild the DLL (if needed) when you build the exe.

Comment: Thanks! I was searching my ass off in the Project Properties of my exe.

Comment: Yeah, there's so many options and places to look that it's hard to find what you're looking for.